How can I update custom column customer payment apply date?
I am trying to update a column in a sublist record using two scripts.
The first one is a file that I will want to be shared.
const APPLY_SUBLIST_ID = 'apply';
const CUSTBODY_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_APPLY_DATE =
  'CUSTBODY_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_APPLY_DATE';

/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NModuleScope Public
 *
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/log'], (record, log) => {
  const setDatePaymentApplied = (recordId) => {
    log.debug({ title: 'recordId', details: recordId });
    try {
      const paymentRecord = record.load({
        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER_PAYMENT,
        id: recordId,
        isDynamic: true
      });
      // log.debug({ title: 'paymentRecord', details: paymentRecord });

      const lineItemsCount = paymentRecord.getLineCount({
        sublistId: 'apply'
      });
      log.debug({ title: 'lineItemsCount', details: lineItemsCount });

      const fields = paymentRecord.getSublistFields({
        sublistId: APPLY_SUBLIST_ID
      });
      log.debug({ title: 'fields', details: fields });

      [...Array(lineItemsCount)].map((_, line) => {
        const lineItemValue = paymentRecord.selectLine({
          sublistId: APPLY_SUBLIST_ID,
          line: line
        });
        const isPaymentApplied = lineItemValue.getCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: APPLY_SUBLIST_ID,
          fieldId: 'apply'
        });
        log.debug({ title: 'isPaymentApplied', details: isPaymentApplied });

        if (!isPaymentApplied) {
          lineItemValue.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: APPLY_SUBLIST_ID,
            fieldId: CUSTBODY_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_APPLY_DATE,
            value: '',
            ignoreFieldChange: true
          });
        } else {
          const paymentDatePaymentApplied =
            lineItemValue.getCurrentSublistValue({
              sublistId: APPLY_SUBLIST_ID,
              fieldId: CUSTBODY_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_APPLY_DATE
            });
          log.debug({
            title: 'paymentDatePaymentApplied',
            details: paymentDatePaymentApplied
          });
          if (!paymentDatePaymentApplied) {
            const dateValue = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
            log.debug({ title: 'dateValue', details: dateValue });
            const result = lineItemValue.setCurrentSublistValue({
              sublistId: APPLY_SUBLIST_ID,
              fieldId: CUSTBODY_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_APPLY_DATE,
              value: dateValue,
              ignoreFieldChange: true
            });
            log.debug({ title: 'result', details: result });
            lineItemValue.commitLine({ sublistId: APPLY_SUBLIST_ID });
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      log.error({ title: 'Error', details: err });
      throw err;
    }
  };

  return {
    setDatePaymentApplied
  };
});

The other script invokes the first one to update in a sublist the custom column CUSTBODY_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT_APPLY_DATE
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/log', 'SuiteScripts/Utils/applyDatePaymentApplied.js'], (
  log,
  applyDatePaymentApplied
) => {
  const sublistChanged = (scriptContext) => {
    try {
      log.debug({ title: 'scriptContext: ', details: scriptContext });
      applyDatePaymentApplied.setDatePaymentApplied(
        scriptContext.currentRecord.id
      );
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      log.error({ title: 'Error', details: err });
      throw err;
    }
  };

  return {
    sublistChanged
  };
});

I am not getting an error, but this is not working; the column never gets updated. The other steps work and the logs are printed as expected, but the lineItemValue.setCurrentSublistValue does not update the lines. This sublist is different from others because it references invoices.

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].
